# How to copy contents of one branch to other branch?

Tags: git, git-branch

I have 'develop' and 'InitialPomChanges' branches. I want to copy all the contents of develop branch to InitialPomChanges branch.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as duplicate of [Copy changes from one branch to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40975751/copy-changes-from-one-branch-to-another)

Answer (score 58):

Assuming you want to overwrite all the contents of InitialPomChanges with what is in develop (i.e. you want the contents of InitialPomChanges to exactly match develop), do the following:

```
git checkout InitialPomChanges
git checkout develop .  #copies the contents of develop into the working directory
git commit -am "Making InitialPomChanges match develop"
```

This will make the last commit in InitialPomChanges match the last commit in develop. To make future merges between the two branches easier, it would be a good idea to now do a `git merge develop`.

Alternatively, if you want to change the contents of InitialPomChanges and do the merge in one single commit, you can do:

```
git checkout InitialPomChanges
git merge -s theirs develop
```

Comment: top way works much more reliably than merge, because after merging branches many times if you ever make a mistake you may end up in a situation where git says there is nothing to merge because you previously resolved a merge a particular way and it assumes that is what you want but you assume files are now all the same and they are not. When deploying code from staging to prod you should not merge you should copy exact like shown here if you want to avoid serious frustration someday

Comment: @pilavdzice - Im not sure this is ideal advice. With merges you can _always_ return to specific commit changes and determine how to resolve them, branch and then move forward into a different development path. The first solution is an overwrite. Thus you specifically lose local changes. Which is necessary sometimes, but I do not think it should be a regular practice at any time. Staging -> Production should always have a release review check, that is more about process than git - direct copies, are generally bad practice because there is no operation information (log or change info).

Answer (score 14):

You can use `git merge` or `git rebase`

If you are on the InitialPomBranch, you can simply run

```
git merge develop
```

or

```
git rebase develop
```

The first one will merge all the commits of the develop branch on to InitialPomBranch. The second one will put all the commits of the develop branch below the first commit of the InitialPomBranch

Edit: Rebase will change the SHA hashes of all the commits of the InitialPomBranch. So you will have to run

```
git push -f origin InitialPomBranches
```

to push all the changes

Comment: `git rebase` (or force pushing things in general) in public branches might impact the other contributors; consider if they are expected to rebase as well and if a merge isn't simply more appropriate.

Comment: I *think* `git rebase develop` will replay the commits of the current branch onto `develop`, which is the opposite of what the user wants. Also, `git rebase` moves the current branch to the new destination, which is almost certainly not what the user wants to do. I would avoid rebase in this instance.

Comment: @DavidDeutsch, yes it will replay the commits onto develop, but it will happen in the branch InitialPomBranches, thereby changing the ids of the commits in the InitialPomBranches, as I have mentioned in the answer. Not sure what you meant by moves the current branch. I am pretty certain no such 'moving' happens

Answer (score 3):

```
$ git merge develop
```

Make sure that your current branch is **InitialPomChanges**

Answer (score 1):

You can run

```
git checkout develop
git branch -D InitialPomChanges
git checkout -b InitialPomChanges
```

This will erase InitialPomChanges branch and will create a new InitialPomChanges branch with all the contents of develop.

Answer (score 0):

my current branch was `develop` and I wanted to copy my content to `main` branch

so I tried
`git merge main`

this gave me an error because **my main branch was empty**

```
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

so I tried this command

```
git merge main --allow-unrelated-histories
```

and then **I synchronized all the changes**(in vs code look at the bottom left you will get this icon right to your branch name)
it worked