# Git copy changes from 1 branch to the other

Tags: eclipse, git, git-branch

I am currently working on a project with 2 different branches for 2 different versions, I have Version 1.8 and version 1.9, each one is different, and I would like to keep both as they are both still being used. my 1.8 is my master branch, is there any possible way to make the 1.9 branch copy all changes made to the 1.8 branch, I am currently using eclipse with egit, but I am happy to use proper git if the need be.

Comment: Yes, it's called merging, look it up in the gitdocs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35174544/git-how-to-copy-contents-of-one-branch-to-other-branch/35174723#35174723

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse select your project with right click and then Team > Merge > Select the branch 1.8 and solve the conflicts that you might have.

I'll suggest you to use SourceTree if you are new to git it is more easy to use.

Comment: I have tried this, it does not copy from my master, it says that it copied the changes from my master branch, but nothing updates, and my merge option is now blanked out, so I cannot merge