# Copy changes from one branch to another

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I have a branch named `BranchA` from `master`. I have some changes in `BranchA` (I am not going to merge changes from `BranchA` to `master`).

Now I have created another branch from `master` named `BranchB`.

How can I copy the changes from `BranchA` to `BranchB`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as duplicate of [How to get changes from another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37709298/how-to-get-changes-from-another-branch)

Answer (score 171, accepted):

```
git checkout BranchB
git merge BranchA
```

This is all if you intend to not merge your changes back to master. Generally it is a good practice to merge all your changes back to master, and create new branches off of that.

Also, after the merge command, you will have some conflicts, which you will have to edit manually and fix.

Make sure you are in the branch where you want to copy all the changes to. `git merge` will take the branch you specify and merge it with the branch you are currently in.

Comment: Just a note that this is going to create a merge commit which may not be what you want.

Comment: The asker wants changes from BranchA into BranchB, but this answer is merging changes from BranchB to BranchA. Please correct!

Comment: I used git merge DRG origin/master

Comment: What will happen if I delete branch A? Will it affect changes in the branch B?

Comment: I think once you create a branch on your remote repository , you can do a `git fetch` in your local git bash/command line, and then `git checkout "your new branch"` would also work fine. This way your changes will only be copied

Answer (score 73):

Instead of merge, as others suggested, you can rebase one branch onto another:

```
git checkout YourBranch
git rebase AnotherBranch
```

This takes `YourBranch` and rebases it onto `AnotherBranch`.

This effectively looks as if `YourBranch` was branched from `AnotherBranch`, not `master`.

Comment: This is the right answer if one wish to merge the changes from one branch to another branch without disturbing the master branch

Comment: What's the difference in merge and rebase and why is rebase preferred over merge?

Comment: @Coddy: While `merge` creates a new commit when the merge happens. However, `rebase` "integrates" commits from other branch to the current branch. For more info: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing  Advantage of rebase is that it helps to keep commit history "cleaner".

Answer (score 11):

Copy content of **BranchA** into **BranchB**

```
git checkout BranchA
git pull origin BranchB
git push -u origin BranchA
```

Comment: Why do you want to add -u option?

Comment: I don't think this does what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 9):

This is 2 step process

- ***git checkout BranchB*** ( destination branch is BranchB, so we need the head on this branch)
- ***git merge BranchA*** (it will merge BranchB with BranchA. Here you have merged code in branch B)

If you want to push your branch code to remote repo then do

- ***git push origin master*** (it will push your BranchB code to remote repo)

Answer (score 7):

Merge the changes from BranchA to BranchB. When you are on BranchB execute `git merge BranchA`

Answer (score 4):

For me the solution was - stash the current changes in the branch and then switch branches and then apply that stash to that branch.

Answer (score 2):

### Simplified solution using git switch

if you have git 2.23 or above you can use **`git switch`** command to do the same since **`git checkout`** command used for a lot of things which is confusing sometime

```git
// This command will switch(go) to BranchB
// use flag -c if you haven't created this branch yet 
git switch BranchB 


// git merge combines sequences of commits from BranchA to the 
// current branch (which is BranchB)
git merge BranchA
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **tortoise git**.

please follow the below steps.

1. Checkout `BranchB`
2. Open project folder, go to `TortoiseGit --> Fetch`
3. In the pull screen, Change the remote branch `BranchA` and click ok.
4. Then right-click again, go to `TortoiseGit --> Push`.

Now your changes moved from BranchA to BranchB